# Elastic Search Date Range

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query that properly parses date ranges. However, my database has a default value that all dates have a timestamp of 00:00:00. This means that items that are still valid today are shown as expired even if they should still be valid. How can I adjust the following to look at just the date and not the time of the item (expirationDate).

```
{
    "range": {
        "expirationDate": {
            "gte": "now"
        }
    }
}
```

An example of the data is:

```
"expirationDate": "2014-06-24T00:00:00.000Z",
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you look into the [different format options for dates stored in ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html)? If this does not work for you or you don't want to store dates without the time you can try this query, which will work for your exact use case I guess:

```
{
    "range": {
        "expirationDate": {
            "gt": "now-1d"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also round down the time so that your query returns anything that occurred since the beginning of the day:

Assuming that 
*now* is **2017-03-07T07:00:00.000**, 
*now/d* is **2017-03-07T00:00:00.000**

Your query would be:

`{
    "range": {
        "expirationDate": {
            "gte": "now/d"
        }
    }
}`

[elastic search documentation on rounding times](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)